# rsyslog parsing logs with liblognorm

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, rules

I'm trying to use such .rb file to parse logs:

```
version=2

rule=:%Server:char-to:\t%\t%stamp:char-to:\t%\t%ip:ipv4%\t%Site:char-to:\t%\t%BID:char-to:\t%\t%SID:char-to:\t%\t%LD:char-to:\t%\t%UserID:char-to:\t%\t%logged:char-to:\t%\t%event:char-to:\t%\t%User_Agent:char-to:\t%\t%Parameters:rest%
```

Problem is such for strings is working only "char-to" any other like "string-to" or "rest" don't want to work. I figure out most of the things with "char-to" but still need to take everything till end of line from one point. How can i do it?